# Is there any syntax to shorten setting variables on object in new C#

Tags: c#, .net, process

Im curious if there is any way to shorten this code, or make it in one line / statement,

```
        var terraformProcess = new Process();
        terraformProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "terraform";
        terraformProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        terraformProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(repoPath,"terraform");
        Console.WriteLine(terraformProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory);
        terraformProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        terraformProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "init";
        terraformProcess.Start();
        terraformProcess.WaitForExit();

        terraformProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =
            $"destroy --var-file=current.tfvars -auto-approve -var vcd_user={_terraformConf.vdcUsername} -var vcd_pass={CryptoServices.Decode(_terraformConf.encryptedVdcPass)} -no-color";
        terraformProcess.Start();
        var output = terraformProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        terraformProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Ive tried:

```
var startInfo = new StartInfo {
FileName = "terraform",
WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(repoPath,"terraform");
RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Arguments = "init";
};
```

then assigning it to Process.StartInfo, but it looks like there is only getter on Process.StartInfo.

Im just curious if there is a shorter way of doing that, without repeating so many lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use object initializer syntax on multiple levels, i.e

```cs
var terraformProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "terraform",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        // etc ...
    }
};
```

You can read up more on object and collection initializers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), it's an incredibly handy piece syntactic sugar

Comment: Curses. You beat me to it by a mere 10 seconds 

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar seems like you were faster on the delete though (almost deleted mine as well) :P

Comment: `but it looks like there is only getter on Process.StartInfo` - you are setting startinfo? does your code compile.

Comment: @RandRandom [yes it does](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LkXMZD), this is because this shorthand is only syntactic sugar, which gets compiled away into what was written originally. You can see what actually gets compiled using a tool like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgD4ACADAARcAjADoAIuii1MBKugbIA3AFgAUAEgNG1VwDMAgEwDBAdlUBvVWq779li+rUA3KAj54+AXj6YIAdz4ACggEDCjIlmr2mgDKMC4wAJKYYASefBGRGWoAYuhEEAByUAC2EGkARDgICFApCMXlADSqfK1t7R18AKrIENEAFhBERACiAB4QDHA4adRwEBkAvhGLyiqdrS0beMKx8QAUAJRrassqZ0A==)

Comment: and it seems OP's claim there is only a getter is incorrect | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo

Comment: Ah oops, automatically assumed you were OP, I corrected my comment. Plus, seems like OP really is lying, even [ancient versions of the .NET Framework include a setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=netframework-1.1)

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to do it like this:

```cs
var terraformProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("terraform", "init")
                                     {
                                         UseShellExecute = false,
                                         // ...
                                     });
```

That will alleviate the need for the separate `Start` call. That line could be the straw that breaks the camel's back.